# C++ OpenMP and std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, openmp, stdvector

Why does the following code not work (as excpected) for std::vector of bool ?
Some elements are randomly false in the bool-vector.
For the int vector all works fine (tested with many more than just 3 loops).

I am on ubuntu 14.04 64bit with g++ 4.8.4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class TestBool
{
public:
    TestBool() {}
    bool test() {return true;}
    int testInt() {return 10;}
};
void testBVec(vector<bool> &bv, size_t loop)
{
    cout << "boolvec loop " << loop << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bv.size(); i++) {
        if( ! bv[i])
            cout << "wholy shit with bool at index " << i << endl;
    }
}
void testIntVec(vector<int> &iv, size_t loop)
{
    cout << "intVec loop " << loop << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < iv.size(); i++) {
        if( iv[i] != 10)
            cout << "wholy shit with int at index " << i << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<TestBool> tv(10);
    size_t loops = 3;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < loops; i++ ) {
        vector<bool> bv(10);
        vector<int> iv(10);

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            bv[j] = tv[j].test();
            iv[j] = tv[j].testInt();
        }
        testBVec(bv, i+1);
        testIntVec(iv, i+1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 7):

Most probably it's because `vector<bool>` transformed to array of bits by compiler. Just use `vector<int>` or `vector<char>` storing 0s and 1s into it, if you don't need bit array.

Comment: Thank you too, didm't know that.

Answer (score 7):

[`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is the explicit template specialization which packs boolean values into bits of some integer variables. To make the bits writable by semantically-correct subscript, `vector<bool>::operator[]` returns some [proxy object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/reference/) which is convertible to `bool` and has assignment operator for bool. The proxy objects for different indices may reference the same underlying memory, so simultaneous access to different bits is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

For a competent proof that it's not a compiler bug, see'Data races' section of [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) page:

> Simultaneous access to different elements is not guaranteed to be thread-safe (as storage bytes may be shared by multiple bits).

or Section 23.2.2 of [the C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

> 2. <...> implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.
> 3. <...> As an exception to the general rule, for a `vector<bool> y`, `y[0] = true` may race with `y[1] = true`.

As @Anton advised, use a type other than `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Sergey and Anton answers, let me point out that vector is known to be not thread-safe as described in the Data Races section in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool .

Your alternatives are (as others suggested) either go to vector of other types or protect the statement

```
bv[j] = tv[j].test();
```

with `#pragma omp critical`.